# How do you overlay a seaborn contour plot over multiple matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a contour plot, as shown on the right, the axes of which are returned by a function, and separately a series of six matplotlib subplots displayed as shown on the left.

[image: plots]

Sample code (with formatting and unnecessary code removed):

```
def contour_plot(df):
    df = DataFrame(contour_list, columns = ['N0','DI'])
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
    sns.kdeplot(data = df, ax=ax, x='N0', y='DI', levels=10)
    return f, ax

fig, ax = contour_plot(df)

for i in range(6):
    plt.subplot(3,2,i+1)
    plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y c=C, s=0.1)
    plt.colorbar()
    
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 16)
fig.tight_layout()
```

I want to be able to overlay the contour over each of the other plots, but I'm not sure how to do this? I would hopefully also like to keep the colorbar of the subplot images. Can this be done?

Comment: what if you insert `sns.kdeplot(data=df, ax=plt.gca(), x='N0', y='DI', levels=10)` after `plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y c=C, s=0.1)` in the for loop?

Comment: @Stef I Just tried it out and it works beautifully. Thank you <3